# que es lo es esta mal con router? el metodo estatico me devuelve siempre null

Tags: php, poo, router

```
class Route{

    private static $uriList = array();
    private static $uriCallback = array();

    static public function add($uri, $function){

        self::$uriList[] = $uri;
        self::$uriCallback[$uri] = $function;
    }

Route::add('/', function(){require __DIR__.'/views/home.php';});
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Devuelve `null` dónde?

Comment: el require no se ejecuta

Comment: Pues has un `echo __DIR__.'/views/home.php';` y revisa lo que hay en esa ruta.

Comment: C:/xampp/htdocs/src/views/home.php devuelve lo que seria la ruta correcta... según el repositorio debería ejecutarse el require en la función anónima y redirigirme a home. Así con el resto de las rutas